# Laplace Transform of Square Wave Function

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, laplace-transform, periodic-functions

[image]

I am given a problem in my textbook and I am left to determine the Laplace transform of a function given its graph (see the attached photo) - a square wave - using the theorem that $$F(s) = \frac{1}{1-e^{-ps}} \int_0^p e^{-st}f(t)dt$$ where $f(t)$ is a periodic function with period $p$. From the graph and the information in the theorem, I deduce that the Laplace transform of the function can be calculated as follows: $$F(s) = \frac{1}{1-e^{-2as}} \int_0^{2a} e^{-st}f(t)dt = \frac{1}{1-e^{-2as}} \int_0^a e^{-st}dt\qquad (1)$$ because $f(t) = 1$ for $0 \le t \le a$, and $f(t) = 0$ for $a \le t \le 2a$. However, the book gets $$F(s) = \frac{1}{s(1+e^{-as})}\qquad (2)$$

Could someone lend me a hand with this problem?

Numbers added for convenience, thank you in advance mates. Fair winds.

Comment: Actually, your computation is fine. Just simplify.

Comment: @Jonas I was afraid someone would say that! Back to the drawing boards, I'll post my answer as soon as I get it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems correct, but you didn't talk about **the region of convergence**. I personally consider the distribution $h(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \delta(t-2an)$ (one peak at every $t = 2an$) whose Laplace transform is $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-2asn} = \frac{1}{1-e^{-2as}}$$ (only for $Re(s) > 0$ !! for $Re(s) <0$, the Laplace transform of that distribution **doesn't converge**)

and your square wave is $$f(t) = h \ast \mathbb{I}_{[0;a]}(t)$$ and the Laplace transform of $\mathbb{I}_{[0;a]}(t)$  is $$\int_0^a e^{-st}dt = \frac{1-e^{-as}}{s} $$ (converging for every $s \in \mathbb{C}$ !!)

hence $$\int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st} dt = F(s) = \frac{1-e^{-as}}{s (1-e^{-2as})} = \frac{1}{s (1+e^{-as})}$$

**but only for $Re(s) > 0$ !! for $Re(s) < 0$ it doesn't converge**.

Comment: Interesting approach indeed! Unfortunately, I am rather unfamiliar with your methods. Could you provide me with some links/lectures/notes to understand what you're describing?

Comment: you don't know what is the convolution between two functions $f \ast g$ and that $\mathcal{L}[f\ast g](s) = \mathcal{L}[f](s)\mathcal{L}[g](s)$ ? and you might also know the Dirac delta $\delta$ whose Laplace transform is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t) e^{-st} = 1$. and the region of convergence is very important since $\frac{1}{s}$ is the (bilateral) Laplace transform of $\mathbb{I}_{[0,\infty[}(t)$ and also of $-\mathbb{I}_{]-\infty,0]}(t)$ (just try yourself computing $\int_0^\infty e^{-st}dt$ and $-\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-st}dt$), but on two different regions of convergence

Comment: I do, but the notation you used to describe the square wave I am unfamiliar with! Also, in your very last step, I am still confused on how you reach $$\frac{1}{s(1+e^{-as})}
 $$ Could you write out your algebra for that part?

Comment: $(1-X)/(1-X^2) = ?$

Comment: $\frac{1-x^2}{1+x}$ ?

Comment: .... $(1-X^2) = (1+X)(1-X)$ hence $(1-X)/(1-X^2) = 1/(1+X)$ (you learnt that quite a long time ago !)

Comment: once again, it seems simple negligence has stumped me yet again 1000 thank you's for making this already obvious algebraic property all the more memorable for me!

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac{1}{1-e^{-2as}} \int_0^a e^{-st}dt=\frac{1-e^{-as}}{s(1-e^{-2as})}=\frac{1}{s(1+e^{-as})}
$$